# FastReport.Net - Passing Multiple Values With Seperated Comma

Tags: c#, fastreport

I am using FastReport.Net and I want to passing multiple values in a parameter.
I have dynamic values for this parameter.
For example;

```sql
SELECT * FROM Students
WHERE StuNo IN (@pStuNo);
```

@pStuNocan includes (3, 8, 11), but fastreport does not allow such use.

I could not find any solution on this issue. I'm waiting for your help, thanks.

Comment: See table values paramters! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15,
See JSON, See XML see anything but splits of string

Comment: And see also https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1771/splitting-delimited-strings-using-xml-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

I reached the result by assigning the parameter as a string and then splitting it.
My solution script is as follows;

```sql
SELECT * FROM Students
WHERE StuNo IN(select regexp_split_to_table(@pStuNo,',')::INTEGER)
```